# OR statement in DAX (Power BI)

Tags: powerbi, conditional-statements, dax, iif

I am trying to run this query in PowerBI:

```
= iif (OR( [StationName.Value] = "CONGbann01", [StationName.Value] = "CONGccbr01"),

(Fields!DriftCorrection_pH7Value.Value + Fields!DriftCorrection_pH4Value.Value)/2.0,

Fields!DriftCorrection_pH7Value.Value +Fields!DriftCorrection_pH10Value.Value)/2.0)
```

But I get this error:

> The Value expression for the textrun
> 'DriftCorrection_pH7Value1.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' contains an
> error: [BC30201] Expression expected.

Could you please help? Thanks.

Comment: This does not look like DAX language.